# Powershell v3 Isfilter unnamed script block.

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

The following code snipit works in PowerShell v2, but not v4.. In the release notes for PowerShell v3 is explains that you cannot set the IsFilter property on an unnamed script block. I believe that's exactly what I have, but I don't understand what change to make..

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function Stop-WindowsService 
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $fromPipe,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='static',Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$name,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='dynamic',Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [ScriptBlock]$scriptReturningName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [ValidateRange(1,86400)]
        [int]$timeout = 60
    )

Process {        
    $server = $_
    if($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'dynamic') {
        $scriptReturningName.IsFilter = $true
        $name = ($server | &$scriptReturningName)
    }        
    Write-Verbose "$($server.Name): $name ==> Checking"
    $service = $server | Get-WindowsServiceRaw $name
```

Comment: I have no idea what this is trying to do, some of these parameters are really opaque.  Where'd you find this?

Comment: I don't see a closing brace on the function so I can conclude that part of this is also missing. What is `Get-WindowsServiceRaw` it might have context for this issue. You don't really explain what is wrong. Or show us how you are calling it for example.

Comment: Use a named script block? You can create it from original scriptblock, if you don't care about re-binding it to your session state: `[scriptblock]::Create("process {$scriptReturningName}")`.